# Specify oultine title when several language servers are present

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

when several Language Servers are providing document symbols. They are both displayed in Outline. It seems that the "displayName" of the extension is used to separate the 2 outlines.

Is it possible to provide a specific name?

I would like to provide a shorter ones that the extension display name to improve readability of the outline.

The current outline view looks alike this, cropping names by default as it is too long:

[image: outline with 2 language servers and name cropped]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wasn't possible. But it might be implemented soon: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62839